# C++ Auto Rounding

Tags: c++, rounding

My code down below is automatically rounding the input.
I dont see any function to round the input anywhere.
Can someone take a look?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
 {
     string input = "";
     int weight = 0;
     int height = 0;
     int bmi = 0;
     while (true) 
     {
         cout << "Enter weight: ";
         getline(cin, input);
         // This code converts from string to number safely.
         stringstream myStream(input);
         if (myStream >> weight)
             break;
         cout << "Invalid number, please try again" << endl;
     }
     while (true) 
     {
         cout << "Enter height: " << endl;
         getline(cin, input);
         // This code converts from string to number safely.
         stringstream myStream(input);
         if (myStream >> height)
             break;
         cout << "Invalid number, please try again" << endl;
      }
      bmi = height * height;
      bmi = weight/bmi;
      if(bmi > 25) 
      {
          cout << "Overweight" << endl;
      } 
      else if(bmi < 18.5) 
      {
           cout << "Underweight" << endl;
      }
      else 
      {
           cout << "Normal weight" << endl;
      }
}
```

Comment: Please include more info on how you know that the input is rounded.

Comment: I was doing a competition question and they provided us sample inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are experiencing a problem called [integer truncation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb7fdy7e.aspx). This can easily be fixed by using a floating type, such as `double` or `float`.